# Struts2-JSON plugin working?

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts2-json-plugin

I know that Struts2 JSON Plugin converts whole `Action` class into JSON form and by supplying a `root` `param` we can let it convert only one `param` into JSON form.

What if I want out of 5 members of my action class, only 2 or 3 of my members to be converted to JSON?
Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `includeProperties` or `excludeProperties`.

`IncludeProperties` didn't worked as expected in my case & hence, I prefer using `exludeProperties` instead.

The action configuration will look like

```
<action name="camp/ls" class="actions.MyAction">
            <result type="json">
                <param name="excludeProperties">
                    dataIsp,deviceBlacklist,deviceOs,deviceWhitelist,exchanges
                </param>
            </result>
        </action>
```

Comment: @SiddharthTrikha I remember the answers to one of my questions - who said it was a bug & hasn't been rectified yet & hence, use `excludeProperties`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to remove the *getters* from the properties you don't want to be JSONized.

Only (non-*transient*) properties with a *getter* will.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should not use `root` parameter but use `includeProperties` parameter instead. See [this](http://struts.apache.org/docs/json-plugin.html#JSONPlugin-Includingproperties) link for reference documentation.

> A comma-delimited list of regular expressions can be passed to the
>   JSON Result to restrict which properties will be serialized. ONLY
>   properties matching any of these regular expressions will be included
>   in > the serialized output.
>
> #### Note:
>
> Exclude property expressions take precedence over include property
>   expressions. That is, if you use include and exclude property
>   expressions on the same result, include property expressions will not
>   be applied if an exclude exclude property expression matches a
>   property first.
>
> ```
> <!-- Result fragment -->
> <result type="json">
>   <param name="includeProperties">
>     ^entries\[\d+\]\.clientNumber,
>     ^entries\[\d+\]\.scheduleNumber,
>     ^entries\[\d+\]\.createUserId
>   </param>
>
> </result>
> ```